# Compare cell to an array and return a value in App script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare

i am trying to create an app script to compare a cell value to an array, where column D has values (task1, task2... task6), each task has a level 1 or 2, therefore if column D2 has value "task1" then it is L1 and the value is set in the respective row in column O, it seems that I might have made several errors in the way as i am not getting the result i would like, any help would be much appreciated.

```
function fillValues() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheetByName()
var task = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:D" + spreadsheet.getLastRow())
var taskLevel = spreadsheet.getRange("O2:O" + spreadsheet.getLastRow())
var newRange = []
var newFillValue

task.getValues().map(function(value) {

var L1Tasks = ["task1", "task2", "task3"];
var L2Tasks = ["task4","task5", "task6"];
for (var i = 0; i < L1Tasks.length; i++){ 
if (value[0]==L1Tasks[i]) { 
newFillValue="L1" 
newRange.push([newFillValue]) }
else { newFillValue="L2" newRange.push([newFillValue]) } 
} 
}) 
taskLevel.setValues(newRange) 
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample values of `task` and `newRange` you expect?

Comment: Except for the value getLast(row() , it should be getLastRow()-1 because you start at row 2, I don't know what the problem is.  I suggest you break this line into 4 to clearly see the code `else { newFillValue="L2" newRange.push([newFillValue]) } `.

Comment: The array `L2Tasks` was used nowhere. The range `taskLevel` and the array `newRange` unlikely will have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it. Just a guess. Probably it should be like this:

```
function fillValues() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('xxx'); // <--- your ID and sheet name should be here
    var task = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:D" + spreadsheet.getLastRow());
    var taskLevel = spreadsheet.getRange("O2:O" + spreadsheet.getLastRow());
    var newRange = taskLevel.getValues(); // <-- fill the array with values from the column
    var newFillValue;

    task.getValues().forEach((value,v) => { // <-- the counter 'v'

        var L1Tasks = ["task1", "task2", "task3"];
        // var L2Tasks = ["task4", "task5", "task6"]; // <-- doesn't need?

        for (var i = 0; i < L1Tasks.length; i++) {
            if (value[0] == L1Tasks[i]) {
                newFillValue = "L1";
                newRange[v] = [newFillValue]; // <-- assign the value
            }
            else {
                newFillValue = "L2";
                newRange[v] = [newFillValue]; // <-- assign the value
            }
        }
    })

    taskLevel.setValues(newRange);
}
```

It can be done shorter. For example you can use `if (L1Tasks.includes(value[0]))` instead of the verbose loop, etc.

The shortened version is here:

```
function fillValues() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('xxx');  // <--- paste your ID and sheet name
    var tasks = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    var levels_range = sheet.getRange('O2:O' + sheet.getLastRow());
    var levels = levels_range.getValues();
    var L1Tasks = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3'];

    for (var row in tasks) {
        levels[row] = L1Tasks.includes(tasks[row]) ? ['L1'] : ['L2'];
    }

    levels_range.setValues(levels);
}
```

**Update**

Here is the variant of the code that hanldes commas in column D:

```
function fillValues() {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('xxx');  // <--- paste your ID and sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var tasks = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var levels_range = sheet.getRange('O2:O' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var levels = levels_range.getValues();
  var L1Tasks = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3'];

  for (var row in tasks) {
    var sub_tasks = tasks[row].replace(/,\s+/g,',').split(',');
    for (var task of sub_tasks) {
      if (L1Tasks.includes(task)) {
        levels[row] = ['L1']; break;
      } else { 
        levels[row] = ['L2'];
      }
    }
  }

  levels_range.setValues(levels);
}
```

**Update 2**

If you want to assign 'L2' for the cells that contain not only 'L1' tasks you can change the inner loop this way:

```
    for (var task of sub_tasks) {
      if (!L1Tasks.includes(task)) {
        levels[row] = ['L2']; break;
      } else { 
        levels[row] = ['L1'];
      }
    }
```

Or (shorter notation of about the same algo):

```
  for (var row in tasks) {
    var sub_tasks = tasks[row].replace(/,\s+/g,',').split(',');
    levels[row] = ['L1'];
    if (sub_tasks.some(x => !L1Tasks.includes(x))) levels[row] = ['L2'];    
  }
```

Or (even shorter), just in case:

```
  for (var row in tasks) {
    var sub_tasks = tasks[row].replace(/,\s+/g,',').split(',');
    levels[row] = sub_tasks.every(x => L1Tasks.includes(x)) ? ['L1'] : ['L2'];
  }
```

Comment: Cheers! For some reason i was getting L2 to be filled in the entire row, after using your second suggestion "includes" it did fix the issue, though I've come across a different issue, the column D might sometimes get more than one task inserted, like "task3, task4" separated by commas, what i need to do is convert the column b in an array so it can be compared with the L2tasks variable, if any of the values is from L2, therefore the value to be set should be L2.
I was considering var splitTask = task.split(","), after that i am stuck on how to compare with the other values, any thoughts?

Comment: I've added the updated variant of the scirpt. Let me know if it works. As for the first issue I can't tell what's going on out there since you didn't provide your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, it did work, the only issue that i am finding is that when at least one of the L2tasks variable appears it should set the value as L2, i have already changed and inserted the L2Tasks variable instead to the code you created and changed if output to be L2 and else to be L1, but still, when there is more than one task separated by commas, it sets the value to L1 to all of them

Comment: I've added the second update to my asnwer. I hope I've got you right. Now it will assign 'L2' for every cell if the cell contains not only 'L1' tasks.

Comment: That pretty much did the job! you made it look so simple and it is very much understandable now, A HUGE thank you for your help!